# Call a script on only the highest numbered file in a directory?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

So what I need to do is go through lots of directories each containing about 5000 numbered files and run an awk script on only the highest numbered file in each one. The files all have the name g091, g092, g093 and so on up to, for instance, g094678. I only want to run the script on the highest one, and it feels like a giant waste of time to get into the directory, look through the whole thing, and then call it specifically on that file. Is there some command I can use to do this for me?

Comment: Please, describe how the files should be sorted. E.g., how would you sort `g091`, `g0923`, `g093`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
ls -1 | sed 's/^g//' | sort -nr | head -1 | sed 's/^/g/'
```

since this gets upvotes I think need to add @glenn jackman's better alternative here

```
ls | sort -k1.2nr | head -1
```

which uses subfield reference in sort.

Comment: Don't need sed at all: tell sort you want the key to start at the 2nd character of the 1st field: `ls | sort -k1.2nr | head -1`